# StanfordCoreNLP Python - Setting properties to the tokenizer

Tags: stanford-nlp

I was using this wrapper to perform tokenization over French sentences.

I also set properties according to the  [CoreNLP page](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html#options), the [Stanford Tokenizer page](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml) and the README here on this [repository](https://github.com/Lynten/stanford-corenlp). However, the properties set in the 'tokenize.options' are having no effect. Is this the way to set properties to the tokenizer?

The code:

```
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'../libraries/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05', lang='fr')`

props = {'annotators': 'tokenize', 
         'pipelineLanguage': 'fr', 
         'outputFormat': 'text', 
         'tokenize.options': 
           'strictTreebank3=false, '
           'untokenizable=allkeep, '
           'escapeForwardSlashAsterisk=false, '
           'normalizeFractions=false, '
           'normalizeAmpersandEntity=false, '
           'invertible=true, '
           'asciiQuotes = false, '
           'latexQuotes=false, '
           'unicodeQuotes=false,  '
           'normalizeOtherBrackets=false, '
           'ptb3Dashes=false, '
           'americanize=false, '
           'normalizeAmpersandEntity=false, '
           'normalizeFractions=false, '
           'normalizeParentheses=false, '
           'normalizeOtherBrackets=false,'
           'ptb3Ellipsis=false, '
           'unicodeEllipsis=false'}

example_sentence = "Maria grandit au sein d'une famille de l'ancienne «bourgeoisie»."

nlp.annotate(example_sentence, properties=props)
```

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Anyone have ideas?